# Multiple Member Functions or One Function With an Enum

Tags: function, interface, enums

I'm looking for a bit of clarity here.  For one of my projects, I wrote a container that holds a bunch of different geometrical shapes.  My interface is as such:

```
Container::AddTriangle(Point, Point, Point);
Container::AddSquare(Point, Point, Point, Point);
```

and so on and so forth.  I like this interface since it does a compile-time check to make sure you have the data that you need.  However, in discussions with my team, someone proposed this interface instead:

```
enum SHAPE { Triangle, Square };
Container::AddShape( std::vector<Point>, SHAPE );
```

With the argument that it provides cleaner code by only having one function instead of many.  While I certainly prefer the first method, I don't have really any argument against the second one.  Has anyone encountered this choice before?  Is one choice better (or at least traditionally preferred) to the other?

**Note:** Before someone proposes:

```
Container::Add( Shape )
```

I would like to let you know that this is not a good solution to my specific problem.  I promise.

Comment: What do you do with the shapes? How are they stored in the container?

Comment: They end up being stored in a graph structure, with the node containing a boost::variant for what shape it is, and edges connecting to nodes representing points (the Points in the above question are really handles to the internally stored nodes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for the first version. Having a single function `Add(std::vector<Point>, SHAPE)` just adds lots of undefined cases, e.g. what do you do if you want to add a triangle with 10 elements in the vector?

Functions like AddTriangle, AddSquare and so on are cleaner and it's easier to see what gets added in the code. Having a function `AddPolygon(std::vector<Point>)` could be used for adding generic shapes.

Even if you store your shapes as a `std::vector<Point>` in the `Container` class I would still prefer the first version. You can just create the vectors in the AddTriangle/AddSquare functions.

Comment: I'm marking this one as accepted since we decided to go with this for our solution, and you answered first.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The principal argument against the second one is that it ignores the fundamental utility of having two distinct functions: Triangle and Square are two distinct entities. The code is clear and unambiguous when there are two separate functions with two separate parameter lists.

One function does nothing to simplify the code, for one the vector causes confusion: Why have an enum when you could determine the shape by the size of the vector? What if you want a triangle with 4 points, what does the software do then? Clearly this is not cleaner. Additionally instantiating the vector when calling the function will be significantly more complicated then simply instantiating the points individually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not both? It seems like there are two separate concerns here: the interface and the implementation. The first is a better interface because the parameters are explicit, but if each function is nearly the same, they should all be using the same implementation. In other words, `AddTriangle` should do nothing but call `AddShape(vector, Triangle)`, while external users of the container should use `AddTriangle` but not work with `AddShape` directly.